# Asking "are you sure" then letting user correct not working

Tags: python

Ok, sorry the title is not very clear, but I'm creating a simple "are you sure" prompt in Python. The basic flow is this -

[Ask for IP] > User enters <0.0.0.1>

[Python]: Are you sure 0.0.0.1 is the correct IP? You won't be able to change this later!

**From now, if the user says Yes, then everything is OK.**

However, if the user replies No, the script lets the user enter the IP again. When prompted for correction again, if the user confirms it's okay now, the script returns None for the IP variable. Here's my code...

```
def get_thingies(): 
    YesNoIP = "none"
    while YesNoIP != "y" and YesNoIP != "n":
        try:
            temp = raw_input('Do you have an IP / domain name? Y/N: ').lower()
            if temp != "y" and temp != "n":
                print('Please enter Y or N')
            else:
                YesNoIP=temp
        except ValueError:
            print('Please enter Y or N');
            YesNoIP = 'none'
def askIP():
    TheIP = raw_input('Okay, what is it? E.X 112.13.141.9: ')
    if AskYesNo('Are you sure '+TheIP+' is the correct IP? You will not be able to change this later!!') != True:
        print('Ok, get it right this time!');
        askIP()
    else:
        return TheIP
if YesNoIP == "n":
    print(help_things[0])
else:
    IPConf = askIP()
    print(IPConf)
get_thingies();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make the recursive call to `askIP()`, you're not returning its value.

```
def askIP():
    TheIP = raw_input('Okay, what is it? E.X 112.13.141.9: ')
    if AskYesNo('Are you sure '+TheIP+' is the correct IP? You will not be able to change this later!!') != True:
        print('Ok, get it right this time!');
        return askIP()
    else:
        return TheIP
```